# Display taxonomy image with WooCommerce ajax search pro plugin results

Tags: ajax, wordpress, search, plugins, woocommerce

I use [Ajax search pro V4.9.1 plugin](https://codecanyon.net/item/ajax-search-pro-for-wordpress-live-search-plugin/3357410) for my WooCommerce. It shows only product image. and doesn't get featured image of taxonomy which listed as result of search.

How can I display Thumbnail image for taxonomy, in my search results?

Thanks.